# Small issue with my coding in C using stdio.h

Tags: c, stdio, cstdio

I am currently working on a code and I keep having issues with my code. I will add it below, but for some reason, whenever I ask for the input, it skips over the second scanner and goes straight to the third. Does anyone know what the issue may be?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a,b,c,d;
    printf("Please input the price of your shopping items:");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Item 1:");
    scanf("%c", &a);
    printf("Item 2:");
    scanf("%c", &b);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Item 3:");
    scanf(" %c", &c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make line 8  and 10 to be like line 13.

Comment: Please note that C and C++ are distinct languages. Please choose one and tag the question appropriately.

Comment: `"it skips over the second scanner and goes straight to the third"` -- The second `scanf` simply reads the newline character of the first. See the duplicate questions for further information.

Comment: Why are you reading characters for prices?  Usually, a price is a number, not a single character.